# In Raku, how does one calculate the sum of positive divisors from a prime factorization?

Tags: key-value, raku

---

In Raku, given a list of pairs `(2 => 3, 3 => 2, 5 => 1, 7 => 4)` ( representing the prime factorization of *n = 2 <sup>3</sup> · 3 <sup>2</sup> · 5 <sup>1</sup> · 7 <sup>4</sup>* ), how does construct a Raku expression for *[**σ(n)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)* = ( 2 <sup>0</sup> + 2 <sup>1</sup> + 2 <sup>2</sup> + 2 <sup>3</sup> ) · ( 3 <sup>0</sup> + 3 <sup>1</sup> + 3 <sup>2</sup> ) · ( 5 <sup>0</sup> + 5 <sup>1</sup> ) · ( 7 <sup>0</sup> + 7 <sup>1</sup> + 7 <sup>2</sup> + 7 <sup>3</sup> + 7 <sup>4</sup> ) ?

```
sub MAIN()
  {
  my $pairList = (2 => 3, 3 => 2, 5 => 1, 7 => 4) ;
  say '$pairList' ;
  say $pairList ;
  say $pairList.WHAT ;
  # Goal:
  #   from $pairList,
  #   the product (1 + 2 + 4 + 8) * (1 + 3 + 9) * (1 + 5) * (1 + 7 + 49 + 343 + 2401)
  #   = sigma ( 2^3 * 3^2 * 5^1 * 7^4 )
  } # end sub MAIN
```

---

##### Update 1

Based upon the answer of @raiph, the following program breaks the overall process into stages for the newcomer to Raku (such as me) …

```
sub MAIN()
  {
  my $pairList = (2 => 3, 3 => 2, 5 => 1, 7 => 4) ;
  say '$pairList' ;
  say $pairList ;
  say $pairList.WHAT ;

  # Goal:
  #   from $pairList,
  #   the product (1 + 2 + 4 + 8) * (1 + 3 + 9) * (1 + 5) * (1 + 7 + 49 + 343 + 2401)
  #   the product (15) * (13) * (6) * (2801)
  #   sigma ( 2^3 * 3^2 * 5^1 * 7^4 )
  #   3277170

  # Stage 1 : ((1 2 4 8) (1 3 9) (1 5) (1 7 49 343 2401))
  my $stage1 = $pairList.map: { (.key ** (my $++)) xx (.value + 1) } ;
  say '$stage1 : lists of powers' ;
  say $stage1 ;
  say $stage1.WHAT ;

  # Stage 2 : ((1 + 2 + 4 + 8) (1 + 3 + 9) (1 + 5) (1 + 7 + 49 + 343 + 2401))
  my $stage2 = $stage1.map: { sum $_ } ;
  say '$stage2 : sum each list' ;
  say $stage2 ;
  say $stage2.WHAT ;

  # Stage 3 : (1 + 2 + 4 + 8) * (1 + 3 + 9) * (1 + 5) * (1 + 7 + 49 + 343 + 2401)
  my $stage3 = $stage2.reduce( &infix:<*> ) ;
  say '$stage3 : product of list elements' ;
  say $stage3 ;
  say $stage3.WHAT ;
  } # end sub MAIN
```

---

A related post appears on [**Mathematics Stack Exchange**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484414/what-are-the-most-efficient-ways-to-calculate-the-sum-of-positive-divisors-funct).

---

##### Update 2

My original motivation had been to calculate [**aliquot sum**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sum) *s(n) = σ(n) - n*.  I found that prime factorization of each *n* is not necessary and seems inefficient.  Raku and C++ programs calculating *s(n)* for *n = 0 … 10 <sup>6</sup>* follow …

###### Raku

```
sub MAIN()
  {
  constant $limit = 1_000_000 ;

  my @s of Int = ( 1 xx ($limit + 1) ) ;
  @s[0] = 0 ;
  @s[1] = 0 ;

  loop ( my $column = 2; $column <= ($limit + 1) div 2; $column++ )
    {
    loop ( my $row = (2 * $column); $row <= $limit; $row += $column )
      {
      @s[$row] += $column ;
      } # end loop $row
    } # end loop $column

  say "s(", $limit, ") = ", @s[$limit] ; # s(1000000) = 1480437
  } # end sub MAIN
```

###### C++

###### (Observed to execute significantly faster than Raku)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std ;

int main ( void )
  {
  const int LIMIT = 1000000 ;
  vector<int> s ( (LIMIT + 1), 1 ) ;
  s[0] = 0 ;
  s[1] = 0 ;
  for ( int col = 2 ; col <= (LIMIT + 1) / 2 ; col++ )
    for ( int row = (2 * col) ; row <= LIMIT ; row += col )
      s[row] += col ;
  cout << "s(" << LIMIT << ") = " << s[LIMIT] << endl ; // s(1000000) = 1480437
  } // end function main
```

---

Comment: "(Observed to execute significantly faster than Raku)" An idiom for eliminating almost all startup and teardown overheads is `say now - INIT now`. The first `now` in the source code is the time when the `say now` is evaluated. The second `now` in that same line is the time the compiler ran the `INIT now` code which would be during [the `INIT` phase](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/INIT) -- after compilation but before the main part of the program. To set my/our expectations low I'm going to guess Rakudo is 1,000X slower than C even with that overhead removed. Did I guess too slow or too fast?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There'll be bazillions of ways. I've ignored algorithmic efficiency. The first thing I wrote:

```
say [*] (2 => 3, 3 => 2, 5 => 1, 7 => 4) .map: { sum .key ** my $++ xx .value + 1 }
```

displays:

```
3277170
```

## Explanation

```
 1 say
 2  [*]                       # `[op]` is a reduction. `[*] 6, 8, 9` is `432`.
 3    (2 => 3, 3 => 2, 5 => 1, 7 => 4)
 4      .map:
 5        {
 6          sum
 7            .key            # `.key` of `2 => 3` is `2`.
 8              **
 9                my          # `my` resets `$` for each call of enclosing `{...}`
10                  $++       # `$++` integer increments from `0` per thunk evaluation.
11                    xx      # `L xx R` forms list from `L` thunk evaluated `R` times
12                      .value + 1
13        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that Raku is ever going to be faster than C++ for that kind of operation. It is still early in its life and there are lots of optimizations to be gained, but raw processing speed is not where it shines.

If you are trying to find the aliquot sum for all of the numbers in a continuous range then prime factorization is certainly less efficient than the method you arrived at. Sort of an inverse Sieve of Eratosthenes. There are a few things you could change to make it faster, though still probably much slower than C++

About twice as fast on my system:

```
constant $limit = 1_000_000;

my @s = 0,0;
@s.append: 1 xx $limit;

(2 .. $limit/2).race.map: -> $column {
    loop ( my $row = (2 * $column); $row <= $limit; $row += $column ) {
       @s[$row] += $column ;
    }
}

say "s(", $limit, ") = ", @s[$limit] ; # s(1000000) = 1480437
```

Where the prime factorization method really shines is for finding *arbitrary* aliquot sums.

This produces an answer in fractions of a second when the inverse sieve would likely take hours. Using the [Prime::Factor module](https://raku.land/github:thundergnat/Prime::Factor): from the Raku ecosystem

```
use Prime::Factor;
say "s(", 2**97-1, ") = ", (2**97-1).&proper-divisors.sum;
# s(158456325028528675187087900671) = 13842607235828485645777841
```